# JPanel does not appear after click JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jbutton

My JPanel doesn't show up when my JButton is clicked. It does shows up when I add the JPanel in my go() method. However, once I tried to execute it by click the JButton, it doesn't work. The program does goes into the loop of the actionPeformed() method of the listener though.

```
public class MyShape 
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton drawButton;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        MyShape test = new MyRandomShape();
        test.go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        drawButton = new JButton("Draw Shape!");
        drawButton.addActionListener(new DrawListener());

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(drawButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }    

    private class DrawListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(empty)
            {
                System.out.print("IN");
                panel = new DrawPanel();
                frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }     

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponents(g);

            int randNo = (int)(Math.random() * 3);

            int width = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth());
            int height = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight());
            int xpos = getWidth()/2-width/2;
            int ypos = getHeight()/2-height/2;

            int v1 = (int)(Math.random() * 256);
            int v2 = (int)(Math.random() * 256);
            int v3 = (int)(Math.random() * 256);

            g.setColor(new Color(v1, v2, v3));

            if(randNo == 0)
            {   
                g.fillOval(xpos, ypos, width, height);
            }
            else if(randNo == 1)
            {
                g.fillRect(xpos, ypos, width, height);
            }
            else
            {
                int startAngle = (int)(Math.random() * 360);
                int arcAngle = (int)(Math.random() * 360);
                g.fillArc(xpos, ypos, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

How do I get the JPanel to show up once the button is clicked?

Comment: panel.setVisibile(true)?

Comment: @DHT, i believe this `frame.setVisible(true);` makes it for it.
Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `parentComponent.revalidate()` every time you do one or more `parentComponent.add(childComponent)` (or change its children  in other ways, such as reorder or remove them).

In your case, your code should be

```
private class DrawListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(empty)
        {
            System.out.print("IN");
            panel = new DrawPanel();
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.revalidate(); // <---------- important
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. However, it duplicates the JButton which I do not want. Is there a way to prevent the duplication of the JButton?

Comment: Since the DrawPanel is the only thing you want to show, why not call `frame.removeAll();` before adding it? That would ensure that the button is removed. Alternatively, you can remove the JButton directly.

Answer (score 1):

Few changes, check this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyShape test = new MyShape();
    test.go();
}

public void go() {
    drawButton = new JButton("Draw Shape!");
    drawButton.addActionListener(new DrawListener());

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel = new DrawPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private class DrawListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            frame.getContentPane().remove(1);
            panel = new DrawPanel();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.repaint();
            frame.validate();

    }
}
```